# How to cap the cardinality to some threshold with Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm trying to find the number of unique values when filtering over a given name,
the problem comes when the number of results is too big which increases the time to find the exact cardinality.
I actually don't need the exact cardinality, It's also fine to limit the maximum unique values we search for to 10000, and then stop searching for more.

**This is the current query:**

```
GET /my_index/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "simple_query_string": {
          "query": "abc*",
          "fields": ["name"],
          "analyzer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_values": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "name.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Current response:**

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 12,
    "successful" : 12,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "unique_values" : {
      "value" : 98504
    }
  }
}
```

**I would expect the desired query to look something like this:**

```
GET /my_index/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "simple_query_string": {
          "query": "abc*",
          "fields": ["name"],
          "analyzer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_values": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "name.keyword"
        "limit": 10000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**The desired response:**

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 12,
    "successful" : 12,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "unique_values" : {
      "value" : 10000
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to cap the cardinality to some threshold. However, you have two ways of speeding up the aggregation computation.

A. By playing with the [`precision_threshold` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_precision_control). As the default is 4000, try 10000.

B. Using [pre-computed hashes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_pre_computed_hashes), because if hashes are pre-computed they don't need to be computed at query time everytime.

Comment: We couldnot use sampler aggregation here?

Comment: @LeBigCat the sampler aggregation works in conjunction with a scoring query and will only aggregate top-scoring documents. If the highly relevant matches contribute to more than the 10K threshold desired by the OP, then yes that could be a solution, but if the majority of distinct elements are in the long tail, then the count will be off. Besides, I'm not sure it would always be faster. Something to be tested on the OP's specific dataset, though.

Comment: Raising the precision threshold speeds up the query? I see this happens in my queries but it is very counterintuitive and I found no trace for this in the docs or anywhere else. Allowing more memory to be consumed translates to a speed up? Why not always use a high threshold - I assume it won't crash due to insufficient memory for a specific query.

Comment: It might seem counter intuitive at first but if you allow more memory (provided the node has some spare memory to use), the computation can usually run faster.